# Como traer de un registro lo que contiene en el campo tipo ManyToManyField con Django

Tags: html, python, django, sqlite3

Explico mi problema:
Lo que quiero es que se me muestren los cursos que tiene un preceptor.
En models donde cree lo siguiente

```
class Cursoos(models.Model):
    curso = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    division = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
    curso_y_division = self.curso + "-" + self.division
    return curso_y_division

class Preceptor(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    ...
    ...
    cursos = models.ManyToManyField(Cursoos)
```

quiero mostrar los cursos que tiene el preceptor a cargo.
Por ejemplo en el views hice:

```
from usuarios.models import Preceptor, Cursoos
def main(request):
    cursosPreceptor = request.user.preceptor.cursos
    cont = {
         "cursosPreceptor":cursosPreceptor,
    } 
    return render(request, "preceptor/main.html", cont)
```

luego en el html

```
{% extends 'preceptor/base.html' %}
{% block content %}

     {{cursosPreceptor}} <br>
     {{user.preceptor.cursos}}

{% endblock %}
```

en ambos el resultado me da

> usuarios.Cursoos.None
> usuarios.Cursoos.None

alguien sabe como puedo mostrar lo que contiene ese campo del usuario preceptor?
aclaro que en el panel de administración cree el preceptor y le agregue 2 cursos, pero no muestra ninguno.

** prueba (no tan importante) **

probé con un

```
{% for cursos in cursosPreceptor%} 
      {{cursos}}
{% endfor %}
```

pero me salto un error al cargar la vista que decia

> ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable

comprendo el error así que no hace falta aclararlo pero no encuentro una solución

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema esta aqui

```
cursosPreceptor = request.user.preceptor.cursos
```

Intenta cambiarlo por

```
preceptor_user = Preceptor.objects.get(user=request.user)

cursosPreceptor = preceptor_user.cursos.filter()
```

///////

**preceptor_user** : obtiene objectos desde el modelo Preceptor solo del usuario request.user (El usuario que ha iniciado sesión)

**cursosPreceptor** : Luego filtra esos objectos por cursos.

**Nota**
Debes saber que esta vista solo puede ser accesible con usuarios autentificados. ya que request.user obtiene el usuario que ha iniciado sesión.

Si cierras sesión y entras a esa vista vas a obtener un error, y si quieres que haya un filtro por cada usuario, tendrás que crear un parámetro de URL y pasar ese parámetro a la vista.